# Можно ли развернуть кубернетис на одном веб сервере?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Доброго времени суток!

Добрался в своём изучени кубернетиса до практики разворачивания кубера на сервере. Есть разные сценарии развёртывания. Я выбрал kubespray. Подскажите можно ли как-то на хосте развернуть кубер? Или необходимо создавать виртульаные машины, настраивать менжду ними сеть и только после этого разворачивать кластер?

Comment: Если цель практика в таком виде, как оно будет использоваться в реальной жизни, то нужно использовать несколько машин реальных или виртуальных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и на одном хосте, способов много:

- https://birthday.play-with-docker.com/kubernetes-docker-desktop/
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind
- https://k3s.io/

и т.д. и т.п.